# Create a custom "Hell Fire Ring" for a different class

Tags: diablo-iii

They have "Hellfire Ring" and "Hellfire Ring Of...". If I am playing a Monk, and want to create a Hellfire ring, it will always have my stat of Dexterity. However, what if I wanted to make a ring for another character of mine.

Assuming I wanted to create a "Hellfire Ring of Intelligence" with my Monk, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Diablo 3, your loot chest, Blacksmith and Jewler are linked to your account, not your character.

If you log in from a differant character, they will all have the same recipes and levels.

Put all the reagents in your chest, and log in to a character with the corresponding [primary statistic](http://www.diablowiki.net/Main_stat):

- **Dexterity**: Monk, Demon Hunter.
- **Intelligence**: Wizard, Witch Doctor.
- **Strength**: Barbarian, Crusader.

You should find that you can make the required ring from your blacksmith, even on a newly-created level 1.

I am also pretty sure that you can craft with materials that are still in your chest, so you probably just have to put the materials in the chest, and won't have to bother withdrawing them into your new characters inventory.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to gather all of the materials (you can do that with your Monk), switch to a Wizard or Witch Doctor and then create the Hellfire Ring with that character.